# Reference request: Existence of a Borel probability measure on a metric space with no support.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the existence of a Borel probability measure on a metric space with no support?

I have seen examples of Borel probability measures with no support but they contain concepts way beyond my comprehension. Specifically i have found the two constructions: Example 7.1.3. in Bogachev's Measure theory Vol. 2 and Example 12.15 in Aliprantis & Border's Infinite Dimensional Analysis, where they construct probability measures with no support. My prerequisites are insufficient to understand these examples, so I have no idea if the topological spaces considered are metrizable.

I have also read [this MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44408/does-the-support-of-a-borel-probability-measure-always-have-full-measure-in-a-me) question and the answer of Joel David Hamkins seems to be what I am looking for, but I don't feel comfortable referencing a MO answer.